# Unable to properly enter arguments for java file

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I apologize for the simplicity of this problem.

I'm trying to use a program called ChromHMM to analyze some biological data. I try and run the program according to the instructions but can't seem to enter the arguments correctly.

Here is an example:
    E:\ComputationalAnalysis\ChromHMM>java -mx1600M -jar ChromHMM.jar BinarizeBed
    chromosomelengthfile=\CHROMSIZES\hg19.txt inputbeddir=\Donor1 cellmarkfileta
    ble=\Donor1\cellmarkfile.txt outputbinarydir=\firstoutput

It returns just this:
    usage BinarizeBed [-b binsize][-c controldir][-center][-colfields chromosome,sta
    rt,end[,strand]][-e offsetend][-f foldthresh][-n shift][-o outputcontroldir][-p
    poissonthresh][-peaks][-s offsetstart][-strictthresh][-t outputsignaldir][-u pse
    udocountcontrol][-w flankwidthcontrol] chromosomelengthfile inputbeddir cellmark
    filetable outputbinarydir

In the manual it says the 4 arguments at the end are the only ones required to run. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm trying to do this from the windows command prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try removing the name of the argument and the equals;just pass the value. so in your example you would have the following.

`E:\ComputationalAnalysis\ChromHMM>java -mx1600M -jar ChromHMM.jar BinarizeBed
\CHROMSIZES\hg19.txt \Donor1 cellmarkfileta \Donor1\cellmarkfile.txt \firstoutput`

Comment: Oh thank you so much, that worked. Except I had to change all the directories to the full path. So for the first one e:\computationalanalysis\chromhmm\chromsizes\hg19.txt for the first argument. Do you know if there is a tutorial anywhere that will teach me how to do these things properly? I've had a lot of trouble finding anything but I may just not be using the right vocabulary

Comment: you shouldn't need the full directory if you remove the leading slash.
so change it to CHROMSIZES\hg19.txt

Comment: here is basic command line commands. im not sure if it will help much http://www.computerhope.com/issues/chusedos.htm

Comment: That's actually very helpful since I understand so little of it. Thank you very much for your help.